# Add two dimensional array to improve performance

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I using the code below to convert xml file to excel sheet. but i have serious performance problem as my file size is around 20MB ( around 50,000 lines ). can you help me to modify the code to include two dimensional array section to improve the performance ?

```
Sub Convert_Xml()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Items")
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\shlomoe\Downloads\TEST.xml")

Set myNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("G_1")

For Each myNode In xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("G_1")
i = i + 1
ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORGANIZATION_CODE")(0).Text
ws.Cells(i + 1, 2) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_NUMBER")(0).Text
ws.Cells(i + 1, 3) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_DESCRIPTION")(0).Text
ws.Cells(i + 1, 4) = myNode.SelectNodes("QUANTITY")(0).Text
  
Next myNode

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Writing to an Array Instead of a Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Convert_Xml()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Items")

    Dim xmlDoc As Object: Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    xmlDoc.Load ("C:\Users\shlomoe\Downloads\TEST.xml")
    Dim myNodes As Object: Set myNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("G_1")
    
    Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To myNodes.Length, 1 To 4)
    
    Dim myNode As Object
    Dim i As Long

    For Each myNode In myNodes
        i = i + 1
        Data(i, 1) = myNode.SelectNodes("ORGANIZATION_CODE")(0).Text
        Data(i, 2) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_NUMBER")(0).Text
        Data(i, 3) = myNode.SelectNodes("ITEM_DESCRIPTION")(0).Text
        Data(i, 4) = myNode.SelectNodes("QUANTITY")(0).Text
    Next myNode

    ws.Range("A2").Resize(i, 4).Value = Data

End Sub
```